# Having problems with values returned from django models

Tags: python, django

I have a model that looks like this

```
class Regions(models.Model):
    region_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    country_id = models.IntegerField()
    regionname = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
       return '%s %s %s' % (self.region_id, self.country_id, self.regionname)
```

and a view that gets data from the database

```
get_region = Regions.objects.filter(country_id = country_id)

print get_region
print get_region[0]
print get_region[1]
```

`get_region` returns a list of each line in the database that matched `country_id`:

```
[<Regions: 1 1 Rtest1>, <Regions: 2 1 Rtest2>, <Regions: 3 1 Rtest3>]
```

`get_region[0]` returns the specific line i want, but it is still in the following format:

```
1 1 Rtest1
```

I have tried to get each value from the above individualy with no luck, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `get_region[0].region_id`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In template you may get using the next way:

```
{% for region in get_region %}
  {{ region.region_id }}
  {{ region.country_id }}
  {{ region.regionname }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
get_region = [str(region) for region in Regions.objects.filter(country_id = country_id)]

print get_region 
['1 1 Rtest1'] # excepted results
```